# Why ScrollView automatically scrolled to bottom of screen?

Tags: android, android-scrollview

I want to use `PreferenceFragmentCompat` inside another fragment(ProfileFragment). Here is my `fragment_profile` layout:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">




<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            style="@style/ToolbarStyle"
            android:theme="@style/ToolbarStyle"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ToolbarStyle"
            app:title="@string/profile">


        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/cash"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/ktpay_cash_top_margin"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/balance"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cash"
                tools:text="23423" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tgSymbol"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/bottom_margin_tenge_symbol"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_left_tenge_symbol"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:text="@string/tenge_symbol"

                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/balance"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/balance" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/wallet_recharge_layout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ktpay_balance">


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/wallet_icon"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/wallet_icon_size"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/wallet_icon_size"
                    android:src="@drawable/add_money" />


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/recharge_wallet"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_left_from_wallet_icon"
                    android:text="@string/recharge"
                    android:textColor="@color/recharge_color" />


            </LinearLayout>


            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/bonus_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/bonus_layout"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/wallet_recharge_layout">


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/bonusText"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:text="@string/bonuses_kt"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/amount_bonus"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/amount_bonus"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/bonus_amount_text_size"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/bonusText"
                    tools:text="123213 тг" />

            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/appSettings"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/bonus_layout" />


        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I add to my `FrameLayout` with id `app_settings` my `SettingsFragment` that extends from `PreferenceFragmentCompat`. Everything works great, except when `fragment_profile` is loaded, its content already scrolled to the bottom of the screen. I don't want it to happen. When I remove `ScrollView` from `fragment_profile`, it works as expected. But I need `ScrollView`. The one of the possible causes I think, that `PreferenceFragmentCompat` uses `RecyclerView`. It somehow affects to my UI, because now `fragment_profile` contains `ScrollView` that contains `RecyclerView`. I thought that I need to call `setNestedScrollingEnabled` in `RecyclerView` inside `PreferenceFragmentCompat`, but don't know how to get reference to that `RecyclerView`. So, the base problem is why `ScrollView` inside `fragment_profile` is scrolled to the bottom when it is shown? What can be possible causes to this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Scrollview gains focus on Fragment open. So in order to make sure it doesn't scroll on fragment open add following attributes to the parent `LinearLayout`.

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
```

Comment: Thanks, but didn't help. Solving the problem not knowing the reason of the problem is not the best solution :)

Comment: Why do you have`layout` tag as the root element? You can directly make the `LinearLayout` as your root element. And then try this fix.

Comment: Because I use databinding:)

Comment: Ok try adding  `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"`  and `android:focusableInTouchMode = "true"` to your  `ConstraintLayout` inside `ScrollView`

Answer (score 0):

It can manage by handling view programmatically by taking view on that activity

```
ScrollView scroll_view=(Scrollview) findviewbyid(R.id.scrollview);
scroll_view.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_UP);
```

Comment: I tried it already. Didn't help. Also, I think, this method is just trying to avoid to solve a problem :)